# How to derive the mean $\mu$ from a Multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$. How to show that $E[X] = \mu$?

Using the definition of the expected value of a continuous random variable:
$$
E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x) dx
$$
I develop the expression by using the multivariate Gaussian density function $f_{X}(x|\mu,\Sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^d|\Sigma|}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$:
$$
E[X] = \int_{\Bbb R^d}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^d|\Sigma|}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}}dx
$$

I am quite stuck after that. Please kind minds of Mathematics help!

Comment: (1) Change of variable $y = x- \mu$ and (2) for $ X_0  \sim \mathcal N(0, \Sigma)$, $E[X_0] = 0$ using and odd argument.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net there's a covariance matrix in between, I can't do just =− ...

Comment: The "standard trick" is to consider a normalisation $y = A(x-\mu)$ where $A$ is a square root of $\Sigma.$ This will transform this integral into the product of $d$ standard normal integrals, all of which are zero

Comment: @WilliamM. can you explain a bit more? Thank you

Comment: $\Sigma$ is (identified with) a positive definite matrix and it has a square root, meaning there exists another positive definite matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = \Sigma.$ Then, you have, with $y = A^{-1}(x-\mu),$ $E(X) = c \int (Ay + \mu) e^{-\frac{1}{2} \|y\|^2} dy = \mu$. Just handle the constants carefully and you will reach $\mu.$ You may need a multi-integral change of variables formula.

Comment: If you have first shown that a weighted sum of independent normals is normally distributed and you've derived the mean and variance for the weighted sum, then the linear transformation that has been hinted at here will do the trick.  However, you still need to prove the sum of independent normals is normally distributed.  This is typically done using characteristic functions.